# What do you call the act of pretending to be someone else?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the act of pretending to be someone else? Spies often pretend to be someone else. I was wondering if the word "performance" could be used to refer to the act of pretending spies often do? I am wondering if it's only used for stage actors.

For example:

> The spy got lost in his performance and started believing the lies he
>   put up to the public.
>
> The spy got tired of his performance and decided to behave like
>   himself, which he later regretted when he noticed someone trailing
>   him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impersonating, acting, imitating, mimicking, posing. These are words that could be used to mean pretending to be someone else. Impersonators act like someone else, often with the intent to deceive or amuse. Actors play a character. Poser is a word often used to describe a try-hard. To mimic or imitate means to adopt characteristics of something, not necessarily someone, else.

It's not just used for stage actors, but I think "act" is a better word for your example. "Performance" has connotations of the theatrical which do not always fit with the behavior of spies.